# Magento 2 - add line of code in core file function

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I need to adjust core file function and add just one line of code to it. Question is: What is the best way to do that?

**File:** Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Creditmemo/DefaultCreditmemo.php

**Method:** draw()

[image]

Possible options:

- **Preference** -> copy whole method and add line of code
- **Plugin** -> copy whole method and add line of code
- **Patch**

What is the best option, is there any other appropriate way to do this? I want it to stay persistent also after magento upgrades.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can achieve your desired output/result using **plugin**.

So the best solution is to go with **Preference**, because this is effective than plugin and patch.

This customization will remain safe untill Magento remove this `draw()` function.

Comment: Or if magento change the function, mine with preference will overwrite the new one after upgrade, if it will be changed after magento upgrade..